# Clarification on String Literal based on Java Language Specification

Tags: java

It is mentioned in the Java Language specification

> A string literal is always of type String (§4.3.3).
>   It is a compile-time error for a line terminator to appear after the opening " and
>   before the closing matching ".
>
> As specified in §3.4, the characters CR and LF are never an InputCharacter; each is recognized as constituting a LineTerminator.

But I can create and run the following statement

```
 public class StringOperation {
        public static void main(String ...args){
            String first = "\n";
            System.out.println(first);
        }

    }
```

and I do not see any error. Thanks for all insight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax `"\n"` is a valid, escaped representation of a line terminator, instead of an actual line terminator.  The JLS precludes you from doing something like this:

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklm
   nopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Instead, you have to do:

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijklm" +
    "nopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Answer (score 3):

What this is referring to is an actual line break is not allowed in your String:

```
String first = "

";
```

does not compile. \n is a perfectly valid escaped line break not an actual one.